# How to solve ImportError with pytest and python

Tags: python, pytest, python-import

I've tried to use the solutions already provided but none of them seem to be working.

Here's my project structure-

```
.
├── ent-add-api-consumer
    ├── lambdas
    |      ├─clients
    |      |   ├─http_client.py
    |      |   ├── __init__.py
    |      └─createContingency
    |          ├─ADD_createContingency.py 
    |          └── __init__.py
    └── test
    |     ├─ unit\consumer
    |     |          ├─test_create_contingency_service.py 
    |     |          └── __init__.py
    |     ├── __init__.py
    |     └── conftest.py
    └── .env
```

Here's the starting part of the code to the test file(test_create_contingency_service.py)

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

from freezegun import freeze_time

from clients import http_client
from eis_util_lib_v2.model.http_request import HttpRequest, HttpResponse
from aws_lambda_powertools.utilities import parameters


@freeze_time("2022-06-30")
def test_create_contingency_workflow(
    consolidated_report_item, create_contingency_response
):
```

And I have created a PYTHONPATH environment variable under my system variable:
PYTHONPATH="lambdas:test/unit/"
[system vars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dl78u.png)

I was getting a warning in my file to the import statement `from clients import http_client`

So vscode created a settings.json with below code when I clicked on the fix:

```
{
    "python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
        "./lambdas"
    ]
}
```

(The first line in setting.json is what I added later to debug the error)

Here's my .env file:

```
PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:./lambdas:./test/unit:./test:/venv/bin/python
LOG_LEVEL=INFO
appName=ent-sls-add-api
```

When I try running the test script through -> `python test\unit\consumer\test_create_contingency_service.py`. I get the below error:

```
    D:\Users\SAH5252\.aws\Work\ActiveDriverDiscoveryPython\ent-add-api-consumer>python test\unit\consumer\test_create_contingency_service.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Users\SAH5252\.aws\Work\ActiveDriverDiscoveryPython\ent-add-api-consumer\test\unit\consumer\test_create_contingency_service.py", line 5, in <module>
    from clients import http_client
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'clients'
```

[Error while running the test scripts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0hn8.png)

And when I try to run pytest through this command `python -m pytest test/unit/` in the root folder, I get the below error:

```
D:\Users\SAH5252\.aws\Work\ActiveDriverDiscoveryPython\ent-add-api-consumer>python -m pytest test/unit/
===================================================================================== test session starts =====================================================================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.10.7, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.11.0, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: D:\Users\SAH5252\.aws\Work\ActiveDriverDiscoveryPython\ent-add-api-consumer
plugins: tavern-1.16.5
collected 0 items / 1 error

=========================================================================================== ERRORS ============================================================================================
___________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting test/unit/consumer/test_create_contingency_service.py ____________________________________________________________ 
ImportError while importing test module 'D:\Users\SAH5252\.aws\Work\ActiveDriverDiscoveryPython\ent-add-api-consumer\test\unit\consumer\test_create_contingency_service.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py:126: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
test\unit\consumer\test_create_contingency_service.py:5: in <module>
    from clients import http_client
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'clients'
=================================================================================== short test summary info =================================================================================== 
ERROR test/unit/consumer/test_create_contingency_service.py
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 
====================================================================================== 1 error in 0.61s =======================================================================================
```

[pytest error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xgbS.png)

I've tried giving absolute path to lambdas folder in the PYTHONPATH Variable but I get the same error.
Could this be an issue with PYTHONPATH, that my python interpreter doesn't know the path it needs to look into to find the imported files.
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or if any other configuration is need to run this.

Any help is appreciated thank you.

Comment: please paste the code from the images into the question as text/code, you can (sort of) copy from windows cmd by selecting it and pressing enter

Comment: did you try to do `from .lambdas.clients import http_client`?

Comment: I did try it, I received same kind of error but for the http_client.py file. That file imports some other files present in the lambdas folder.

Comment: alright, well what files does `http_client` use? did you do something like `from ..createContingency import ADD_createContingency` (two dots to go up a directory)

Comment: you might have to google python relative imports and just study how they work, it's not at all self-explanatory

Comment: It uses exception.py in the models folder, which in turn is inside the lambdas folder

Comment: and did you try to do `from ..models import exception` inside `http_client`?